# Sqoop incremental job importing more number of records than in source

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have created sqoop job to import data from Netezza. It imports data by comparing a timestamp column (checking column) from source on daily basis. I am observing that, the job is importing more number of records each day when compared with source table in Netezza.

There seems no problem or error with the job. The 'incremental.last.value' is also updated properly for each run.

How can I find out what is wrong with the job. I am using Sqoop version: 1.4.5.2.2.6.0-2800

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the sqoop job statement used.Have you used any split-by column in the sqoop job, if yes try using other split-by column.

Answer (score 0):

More investigation showed the job is working correctly. Problem is with verification method. I was trying to validate the number of rows on a given date in Netezza and Hive. But, the date value of checking-column gets updated in Netezza. These updates are not reflected on Hive by any means. Hence, the number of records for a day doesn't remain constant at Netezza side.

The problem has given a good learning to first check all the conditions of a scenario under consideration.There may be many factors involved in achieving a output other than just correctness of code written.